# Grammar for language of regular expressions with given alphabet

Tags: regex, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start with this question. The question is to create a grammar for the language of regular expressions with the alphabet `{ ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘|’, ‘*’, ‘(‘, ‘)’ }`. Assume 1 line of input (a single string) and no spaces. Empty string is not valid and it should correctly capture the precedence of the operators which from lowest to highest is union ('|'), concatenation, and kleene ('`*`'). What would be the best way to start writing the grammar for this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Not looking for an answer, just not sure how to start. So far I have something like:

```
S -> S'('S')'S  
   | A  
A -> AA  
   | A'*'  
   | T  
T -> T'|'T  
   | X  
X -> 'a'  
   | 'b'  
   | 'c'  
   | 'd'
```

But I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

EDIT: After doing some more work this is the conclusion I've reached:

```
START -> EXPRESSION  
EXPRESSION -> EXPRESSION'|'EXPRESSION  
EXPRESSION -> PARENTHETICAL'*'  
EXPRESSION -> PARENTHETICAL  
EXPRESSION -> EXPRESSION PARENTHETICAL  
EXPRESSION -> PARENTHETICAL EXPRESSION  
EXPRESSION -> EXPRESSION PARENTHETICAL EXPRESSION  
EXPRESSION -> REPEAT  
PARENTHETICAL -> PARENTHETICAL'*'  
PARENTHETICAL -> '('EXPRESSION')'  
REPEAT -> REPEAT REPEAT
REPEAT -> TERMINAL'*'  
REPEAT -> TERMINAL  
TERMINAL -> TERMINAL'*'  
TERMINAL -> 'a'  
TERMINAL -> 'b'  
TERMINAL -> 'c'  
TERMINAL -> 'd'
```

This can also be written as:

```
S -> E  
E -> E'|'E  
E -> P'*'  
E -> P  
E -> E P  
E -> P E 
E -> E P E  
E -> R  
P -> P'*'  
P -> '('E')'  
R -> R R
R -> T'*'  
R -> T  
T -> T'*'  
T -> 'a'  
T -> 'b'  
T -> 'c'  
T -> 'd'
```

I'm fairly certain this is right, and I double checked it with a bunch of varied test inputs. Any confirmation would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like homework. Is it?

Comment: Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Comment: Yea its homework. Not looking for an answer, just not sure how to start.

So far I have something like:
S -> S'('S')'S
   | A


A -> 

But I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: @TonyDakhoul include that last comment in your question so people read it! It's always a good idea to include directly in your question what you tried !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a question of iteration.  I always like to start with the rule `Start-> NonTerminal`, just to give myself half a chance at a regular grammar.  Nested parentheticals I believe will reduce us to a Context Free Grammar, but that's fine.  I find it makes that step easier.   Then, you have to start with the LOWEST precendence operator.  Parenthetical, and Union in your case.  So, initially:

```
Start -> Expression
Expression -> Expression|Expression
Expression -> (Expression)
```

Note that I have eschewed normal '|' notation because it's one of the symbols in your alphabet.  This avoids confusion.  Then, we can add the next operator, concatenation, with a set of rules that generate repetion.

```
Start -> Expression
Expression -> Expression|Expression
Expression -> (Expression)

Expression -> Repeat
Repeat -> RepeatRepeat
Repeat -> Terminal
Terminal -> a
Terminal -> b
Terminal -> c
Terminal -> d
```

Then, all that's left is to add the Kleene Star as the lowest precedence operator:

```
Start -> Expression
Expression -> Expression|Expression
Expression -> (Expression)

Expression -> Repeat
Repeat -> RepeatRepeat
Repeat -> Terminal
Terminal -> a
Terminal -> b
Terminal -> c
Terminal -> d

Repeat -> Terminal*
Expression -> (Expression)*
```

And we have a grammar that generates all non-empty regular expressions from the desired alphabet.  In more traditional variable notation, it might look like this:

```
S -> E
E -> E|E
E -> (E)
E -> (E)*
E -> R
R -> RR
R -> T*
R -> T
T -> a
T -> b
T -> c
T -> d
```

There's a grammar I'm pretty sure does it.  Hope someone will check my work, because it's been a few years since I wrote a formal grammar.

EDIT:

As a result of said double checking, it was pointed out that concatenating Expressions and Parenthetical Expressions wasn't working.  However, we can add that.  The first step is to add a new rule `Expression -> Parenthetical` and change `Expression -> (Expression)` and `Expression -> (Expression)*` to `Parenthetical -> (Expression)` and `Parenthetical -> (Expression)*` Then, A couple quick rules for concatenating them leads to the ruleset:

```
Start -> Expression
Expression -> Expression|Expression
Expression -> Parenthetical

Parenthetical -> (Expression)
Parenthetical -> (Expression)*

Expression -> Expression Parenthetical
Expression -> Parenthetical Expression
Expression -> Expression Parenthetical Expression

Expression -> Repeat
Repeat -> Repeat Repeat
Repeat -> Terminal
Terminal -> a
Terminal -> b
Terminal -> c
Terminal -> d

Repeat -> Terminal*
```

Comment: Hm.  This doesn't support (E)*, but that's an easy fix.  I'll make it in a moment.

Comment: Question: This grammar you wrote does not allow for something like a(b|c)*d correct?  
  
Also, wouldn't parenthesis technically be the highest precedence? I know its not stated in the problem, but for example this statement:  
  
ab*c|d  
  
Can be thought of like so:  
  
(a(b*)c)|(d)

Comment: This could be fixed by changing `E->(E) and E->(E)*` to `E->P`,`P->(E)` and `P->(E)*`, Then adding the rules `E->EP`, `E->PE` and `E->EPE`.  This could probably be reduced.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. My main take-away from your answer is to always start with the lowest precedence, right? Let me try to rewrite my grammar and I'll repost it soon. Thanks again for your reply, much appreciated!

Comment: Yup.  Don't worry about trying to make a minimal grammar initially, I sure didn't.  Just make each piece work without breaking all the previous pieces.  You can always reduce your grammar later.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I believe I have a correct grammar for the language of regular expressions. If you could double check it just for my sake that'd be great, but either way I really appreciated your help. =]

Comment: @TonyDakhoul Watch out! `EXPRESSION -> PARENTHETICAL'*'` and `PARENTHETICAL -> PARENTHETICAL'*'` could be combined to generate infinite Stars - which isn't valid in regular expressions.  Actually, the second rule can do that by itself.

Comment: Same thing with `TERMINAL -> TERMINAL'*'`

Comment: As far as my teacher mentioned, there can be as many stars as you want, its just redundant. Something like abc**** is valid in the language he wants us to come up with. But other than that, it has your approval?

Comment: @TonyDakhoul - Yeah, I think so.  Again, it's been years since I had to write formal grammars.  I'd do two things:  Double check with your Teacher about the redundant stars, then (if you're allowed) shop it out to some other classmates, or friends who've taken the class before.

Answer (score -2):

What newcomers to compilers have a hard time to understand is that a grammar that is *only* capable of parsing valid input is ***useless***.

A *good* grammar must reflect the hierarchical structure of the input so we can attach semantics to it.

It's all about meaning.

That said, [Grako](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/) has a regular-expression-to-CFG translator as [its only sample project](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/src/03454d10a51cf493bf2f7efb8b65917a2431633d/examples/regexp?at=default).

Comment: This has very little to do with the question asked here.  The question asked was about a Grammar that produced all strings that are valid regular expressions given the alphabet provided, not about creating a grammar from a Regular Expression.  This question isn't about compilers, and your answer (no matter the truth value of the statements made therein) is inappropriate here.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan From the original question "... to create a grammar for the language of regular expressions...", "...should correctly capture the precedence of the operators...". That's precisely what my answer is about.

Comment: That's not at all what your answer is about.  Your answer is about taking a regular expression and turning it into a Context Free Grammar.  Or at least, that's what the sample project you link to does.  That's not what the was asked.  What was asked is how to write a Grammar that generates all valid regular expressions.  It's a very very different process.

Comment: The *language generated by a grammar* is a theoretical concept of little practical use, because most interesting languages are infinite. In practice, with use grammars to build *parsers* that can *verify* is a given sentence belongs to the language, and we write grammars that let us recover the abstract structure of sentences so we can attach semantics to them. At any rate, the grammar I posted as example **does generate the language of regular expressions**, and can be used for any parsing task, or it can be translated to the notation of a different parser-generating tool if so wished.